# Why my placeholder won't work in python for sqlite3 query

Tags: sqlite3-python

I am writing a series of very similar sqlite3 query in python:

```
def spark_plug():
    f = 3 
    s = f - 1
    cursor.execute("SELECT spark_plug FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT ?", (s,))
    result = cursor.fetchall();

def air_filter():
    f = 2 
    s = f - 1
    cursor.execute("SELECT air_filter FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT ?", (s,))
    result = cursor.fetchall();
```

this code look similar so i want to use placeholder in the query, however the placeholder doesn't work

i tried:

```
def periodic(): 
    data=[('spark_plug', 3)]
    cursor.execute("SELECT ? FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT ?", data)
```

but it yield sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

if i change to:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ? FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT ?", ('spark_plug',3))
```

it do not retrieve data from db, but become 'spark_plug' 3 times :[('spark_plug',), ('spark_plug',), ('spark_plug',)]

even i tried reduce 2 placeholder to 1:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ? FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT 3", ('spark_plug'))
or
cursor.execute("SELECT ? FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT 3", 'spark_plug')
```

error still occur: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.

now i changed the placeholder to another parameter, it seem work for me:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT spark_plug FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT ?", '3' )
```

however, when the number become grater than 10, it yield error:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT spark_plug FROM periodic_service ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT ?", '10' )
```

error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

Why my placeholder WONT WORK??

Comment: The placeholder can ONLY be used for column values.  Remember, the purpose of the placeholder is to add quotes, and you NEVER want quotes around LIMIT.  So, just use Python substitution:  `f"SELECT ... ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT {s}"`.

Comment: You should use `SELECT * FROM ` insread of `SELECT ? FROM ` in sqlite3.

Comment: Oh i see. just wonder is there are other way to make the SQL query dynamic by using python? like i may select different field with different limit at the same time. perhaps i can use select * to get the list and filter it using python, but couldn't get different limit.